# Split screen in iPad

Tags: ios, split, ipad

I working on a iPAD only app which requires me to split the screen such a way that:

(1) there are 2 parts on the screen divided vertically

(2) On the left side, user can communicate using a chat

(3) On the right side, user can see continuous streaming data

I am not sure (A) how can I do two tasks simultaneously (B)how to split the screen (is Split view the way to achieve both of these?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A `splitViewController` is great for having two view controllers (or rather the views that belong to them) onscreen at the same time. Usually you see this for master-detail apps, where left you get a table view in which you select a row that gets displayed in detail on the right. Nothing stops you from using this in your own way.

Answer (score 0):

Take RootViewController and inside its 

`-(void)viewDidLoad:`

    `UIView *viewOne = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 512, 768)];

    UIView *viewTwo = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(512, 0, 512, 768)];
    [[self view]addSubview:viewOne];

    [[self view]addSubview:viewTwo];`

And you can add anything inside viewOne or viewTwo.